# EL and hashmaps and dots in name

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, el, tiles

Simple question, but I can't solve it. In servlet I have:

```
HashMap<String,String> map= new HashMap<>();
map.put("view", "/footer.jsp");
request.setAttribute("foot.er",map);
```

And in Tiles xml file I have:

```
templateExpression="${['foot.er']['view']}">
```

All variants I tried didn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestScope['foot.er'].view`, or `requestScope['foot.er']['view']` should work. But you're making your own life difficult by having a dot in the attribute value. Name the attribute 'footer', so that you can use `footer.view`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working. I know about dots but need to use them.

Comment: Can you tell, if I view is also HashMap<String,String> and has string with ID -"name" must this work - requestScope['foot.er'].view.name? I am asking because can't make it to work.

Comment: Yes, it should wor. But once again, this shows a serious design problem. HashMaps containing HashMaps is awful. Define and use Java beans.